# Distinguishing post request's from possible poster elements

Tags: python, html, post, bottle

So, what issue im running into is how do i know what element of my page made a post request? I have multiple elements that can make the post request on the page, but how do i get the values from the element that created the request? It seems like this would be fairly trivial,but i have come up with nothing, and when doing quite a few google searches i have come up with nothing again.

Is there any way to do this using Bottle?

I had an idea to an a route for an sql page (with authentication of course) for providing the action for the form and use the template to render the id in the action, but i was thinking there had to be a better way to do this without routing another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hidden input field to each form on the page with a specific value. On the server side, check the value of this field to detect which form the post request came from.